# Is it safe/defined to assume the value of a Windows pseudo handle?

Tags: c++, windows, handle

I am writing a piece C++ code for Windows that needs to query the timings for the process and each of its individual threads.

To do the necessary system calls, I need the handles for the process and each of its threads. I am using the `getCurrentProcess` and `getCurrentThread` functions which both return a pseudo handle. Upon further inspection, I noticed that the pseudo handles for all threads share the same value.

After a brief search on the internet, I found the following article that reports the same values for the process and thread pseudo handles as I got: https://weseetips.wordpress.com/2008/03/26/getcurrentthread-returns-pseudo-handle-not-the-real-handle/

**My question:** is it safe and/or defined to call `getCurrentThread` once from one thread and use the returned pseudo handle in all other threads to let them refer to themselves?

Using the current implementation, this works as expected. I am just wondering if this behavior is guaranteed. In other words, will it work on any Windows platform that offers the `getCurrentThread` function; and would changing the behavior be considered a breaking change?

---

The [documentation for the `getCurrentThread` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182(v=vs.85).aspx) states (emphasis mine):

> A pseudo handle is a special constant that is **interpreted as the
>   current thread** handle. The **calling thread can use this handle** to
>   specify itself whenever a thread handle is required. [...]

Which makes me believe this special pseudo handle is just an alias for "the current thread" and can therefore be shared among all threads to let them refer to themselves. On the other hand, the documentation also says that the return value can be used by the calling thread, hence my confusion!

Comment: Pseudo handles are like `.` directory entries. If you do `cd AnotherDirectory`, there still is a `.` directory entry, but it now refers to the new current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. From that same page:

> The function cannot be used by one thread to create a handle that can be used by other threads to refer to the first thread. **The handle is always interpreted as referring to the thread that is using it.** A thread can create a "real" handle to itself that can be used by other threads, or inherited by other processes, by specifying the pseudo handle as the source handle in a call to the DuplicateHandle function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This makes pseudo handles quite convenient! Not sure how I read over that piece of the documentation though...

Answer (score 3):

yes, this is safe - this pseudo handles is well known values and documented in `wdm.h` (from windows wdk)

```
#define NtCurrentProcess() ( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -1 )  
#define ZwCurrentProcess() NtCurrentProcess()         
#define NtCurrentThread() ( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -2 )   
#define ZwCurrentThread() NtCurrentThread()           
#define NtCurrentSession() ( (HANDLE)(LONG_PTR) -3 )  
#define ZwCurrentSession() NtCurrentSession()
```

> and can therefore be shared among all threads to let them refer to
>   themselves.

of course no, it can not be "shared among all threads" - only current process/thread can use it for refer to themselves.

when kernel mode api got thread/process handle as input parameter - he need convert handle to object pointer (`ETHREAD` or `EPROCESS`). for this first check for this constant values - if yes - used pointer to current thread/process object. otherwise handle is index in process handle table

Comment: When you say "only current process/thread can use it for refer to themselves", do you mean that I need to call `GetCurrentThread` in each of my processes threads? Or do you mean that I cannot share it cross-process?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: You _can_ share those special values across threads, but they are not magic. In thread A, the value -2 refers to thread A. If you share that value -2 with thread B, it doesn't magically become the real thread ID of A. Instead, thread B gets the numeric value -2, which in thread B refers to thread B and not the original thread A.

Comment: @MSalters That is exactly the behavior I want. But I was unsure if it is defined or guaranteed behavior. Not just an implementation detail that may change in the future.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: Has to be guaranteed for Windows to have backwards compatibility.